# Unity3D C# not going to the else statement (Invoke Repeating)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making my first game using Unity3D written in C#. I've faced some game bug just now, and it's been hours that I've been thinking of what might have been wrong with my code, but I can't see anything wrong.

I have a stat called healthRegen which add HP to the character every second. What I have noticed is even when my player HP drops to zero, it just keep adding HP to my player, thus making it alive again. I have a method that checks if my character HP drops to zero but it didn't call it and I don't know why.

```
   public bool fullHealth() {
        if(currentHealth >= maxHealth) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void adjustHealth() {
        if(currentHealth > maxHealth) {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        if(currentHealth < 0) {
            currentHealth = 0;
        }
    }
```

That is my method and this is my player script

```
 void Start() {
        InvokeRepeating("regenerate", 0f, 1f);
    }
    // Check if the player is still alive
    public bool isDead() {
        if (attribute.currentHealth == 0) {
            return true;        
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Die method
    public void dead() {
        animation.Play(dieClip.name);
    }

    private void regenerate() {
        if (!attribute.fullHealth()) {
            attribute.currentHealth += attribute.healthRegen;
        } else {
            attribute.adjustHealth();
        }
    }
```

This maybe a dumb question for others but I'm sorry, I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that `regenerate()` is adding health to your player if his health is at 0.

You just need to add a call to `isDead()` to prevent this.

```
private void regenerate() {
    if (!attribute.fullHealth() && !attribute.isDead()) {
        attribute.currentHealth += attribute.healthRegen;
    } else {
        attribute.adjustHealth();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out a solution right now, I forgot the CancelInvoke() method

```
private void regenerate() {
    if (!attribute.fullHealth()) {
        attribute.currentHealth += attribute.healthRegen;
    } else {
        CancelInvoke("regenerate");
        attribute.adjustHealth();
    }
}
```

Now it's working perfectly!

Comment: This just makes regeneration stop when you reach full health. If your health goes below full again, it won't regenerate. Is this your intended behavior?

Comment: @Agumander oh I didn't see that. And you're right sire, and that is not what I want to happen

Comment: In your regenerate you should probably check not only whether your health is full, but also whether it is empty. Adding an isDead() check to regenerate should help.